# Ruby and Chef difference in hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, chef-infra

I've been programming in ruby for a little while now and have heard that using symbols for accessing values in hashes is a "better practice" than using strings, e.g.

```
default[:key] = value 
  over 
default['key'] = value
```

I've been working on a chef project and noticed that chef cookbooks use the second way to access hash values (via strings). Often accessing via the symbol alternative does not work!

So I guess my question is two part, should I stop using symbols and use string accessors everywhere? And why does the use of symbols not work?

Comment: See [this comment](https://github.com/acrmp/foodcritic/issues/86#issuecomment-74186035) on foodcritic rule. symbols are converted to string anyway by Chef Mashes accessor, so use strings. Symbols not working are usually when there's an operator (usualy `-` in them).

Comment: Symbols, in plain old Ruby, are similar to string constants in C. When you use them, they effectively exist only once. If you've got loads of them, it can help economise on memory. When strings are used however, they are always immutable instances each time they're declared. It's recommend to [freeze](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-freeze) strings if they're used as constants. To declare a symbol with spaces or other reserved tokens to the Ruby interpreter, declare them like this `:"dashed-symbol"`.

Comment: Thanks! That really sheds some light on the reason why it's suggested to use symbols over string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T.L;D.R. Accessing attributes by symbol is discouraged in favor of strings, despite still in use.

Quoting lamont granquist from Chef in a foodcritic (linter) issue [here](https://github.com/acrmp/foodcritic/issues/86#issuecomment-74186035)

> Chef implementation of Mashes converts all symbols internally to
>   strings

The official [recommendation in docs](https://docs.chef.io/ruby.html#symbols-or-strings) is to use Strings.

To complete the Overview of chef attributes you can also access them as instance method,  I.e. `node.key.subkey` but this method is deprecated and will be removed in short to mid term.

Comment: Symbol keys are not deprecated and will never be removed. It's method-style access that is pending removal.

Comment: I had the feeling I was forgetting something ;) Thanks for the head up @coderanger. Wish to edit or should I do it ?

Comment: Go for it, I'm on mobile for the moment :)

Comment: @coderanger not better, setting kids to bed,  youngest done, oldest will end her anime do homeworks and go to sleep ;) Editing meanwhile

Comment: @coderanger done. Hope I'm right on all points now. If you feel there's missing info, feel free to edit :)

Comment: @Tensibal seems with Chef 13 symbols are very much supported in hashes!

Comment: @skylerto we're talking about chef attributes here, not about a hash you'd put within an attribute. The hash syntax is pure ruby... The advice about using string in **attributes** still stand.

Comment: Fair enough, I saw someone using symbols in a cookbook on the supermarket a little bit ago, can't find it right now though. :(